# Embed a Google Docs in WordPress?

Tags: embed, google-docs

I need to embed a Google Docs / Spreadsheet in one of my WordPress posts.

Unfortunately, this: http://code.google.com/p/inline-google-docs/ does not work with my WP 3.1.3 installation.

I just need something that is as easy as "pasting" the published URL for my Google Docs.

Any advice?

Best Regards,

W

Answer (score 1):

Did you search the Plugin Repository?

There's [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/inline-google-docs/).

There are also [all of these](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/google-docs).

Comment: Inline Google Docs == http://code.google.com/p/inline-google-docs/ For now, I just installed the Iframe plugin since I just want to embed using the URL.